# C++ file stream for reading/writing

Tags: c++, filestream, fstream

I need to open a file for both reading/writing using fstream and read each character then write that character back to the file. for example i have this code.

```
fstream in("test.txt",ios::in | ios::out);
if(!in)
    cout<<"error...";
else
{
    char ch;
    in.seekg(0,ios::end);
    int end=in.tellg();//get the length

    in.seekg(0);//get back to the start
    for(int i=0;i<end;i++)
    {
       //in.seekg(in.tellg());//if i uncomment this the code will work
       if(!in.get(ch).fail())//read a character
       {
           in.seekp(static_cast<int>(in.tellg())-1);//move the pointer back to the previously read position,so i could write on it
           if(in.put(ch).fail())//write back,this also move position to the next character to be read/write
               break;//break on error
       }
    }
}
```

I have a file named `"test.txt"` which contains "ABCD". As i understand it both `put()` and `get()` methods of the stream object move the file pointer forward(i see that by getting the return value of `tellg()` or `tellp()` functions after each `get()` or `put()` method call). My question is when i comment out the code that will seek the stream pointer to "where it is now"(`in.seekg(in.tellg()`), the code will result incorrect results. I don't understand why this is since `tellg()` is showing the correct position of the character to be read next.what is the purpose of explicitly seeking to it? I am using visual studio 2005.

The incorrect result is it writes to the file "ABBB" instead of "ABCD".

Comment: Why are you messing with this `seek` business at all?

Comment: how exactly "wrong" result?

Comment: `tellg()` returns `streampos`, not `int`.  And what is your "incorrect" result?

Comment: @ForceBru Good point! but that aside it is bugging me why i need to seek to where the pointer is currently located to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output buffer has to be flushed when switching between write and read.

```
fstream in("test.txt",ios::in | ios::out);
if(!in)
   cout<<"error...";
else
{
   char ch;
   in.seekg(0,ios::end);
   int end=in.tellg();//get the length

   in.seekg(0);//get back to the start
   for(int i=0;i<end;i++)
   {
      if(!in.get(ch).fail())//read a character
      {
          in.seekp(static_cast<int>(in.tellg())-1);//move the pointer back to the previously read position,so i could write on it
          if(in.put(ch).fail())//write back,this also move position to the next character to be read/write
           break;//break on error

          in.flush();
      }
   }
}
```